# Changing format of the file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, native-file-system-api-js

Can I change the format of the file **by using Native File System API?** For example, when I read the every .pdf files of the one directory and changed them to the .jpeg files?

Comment: Do you want to change their extension or their actual format? Such a conversion is not possible between any two file formats.

Comment: I would like to change the format of the file, I mean I would like to convery .pdf file to .jpeg file with using Native File System API. Is it possible? If it is not, why is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to run the conversion as outlined in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jdeng/cbfad9cb21e452127c81). For the actual folder iteration, try this:

```js
const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
  if (entry.kind === 'file' && entry.name.endsWith('.pdf')) {
    const file = await entry.getFile();
    // Convert to image as outlined in gist.
  }
}
```